# C# cast back to drived type

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

I have a base (it could be a class, abstract class or interface or something else) and derived types. I have a list of derived objects in a base type list. i like to call respective overload for each one. i though it is possible (i remember i tested something similar and it worked some weeks ago) but now it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Something
{
    List<A> list;
    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<A>();
        list.Add(new B());
        list.Add(new C());
        Debug.WriteLine(list[0].GetType());
        foreach (var item in list)
            DoSomething(item);

    }

    void DoSomething(B b)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("b");
    }
    void DoSomething(C c)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("c");
    }

}

interface A
{
}
class B : A
{
}
class C : A
{
}
```

this code doesn't compile because there is no overload that gets `A` but I'm almost sure i have done it before. I have a working solution. I can assign list item to a `dynamic` variable and then pass it to method. but i saw some benchmarks that show reflection and dynamic are very inefficient and performance is very important for me because this process get called many times in a second.

so is a better performance way than using `dynamic` type for this purpose?

Comment: Read on visitor pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of (mis-)using dynamic types to do this, as you can reclaim the full type information otherwise lost, including generic parameters. Even with the language's recent improvements in pattern-matching, it's the most powerful way of doing what you want to do.

Computers are super super quick, and using dynamic dispatch here and there in C# code is unlikely to make any significant difference to performance. Warnings about the slowness of reflection (and there is reflection involved in dynamic dispatch) are somewhat out of date as big improvements were made several years ago.

However...

To do it *properly*, your best option these days is to use C#'s new-ish type-matching switch statements like so:

```cs
void DoSomething(object obj) {
    switch(obj) {
        case B b:
            Debug.WriteLine("b");
            //here 'b' is available as type 'B'
            break;

        case C c:        
            Debug.WriteLine("c");
            //here 'c' is available as type 'C'
            break;

        default:
            Debug.WriteLine("unsightly default case - necessary for safety");
            throw ...
    }
}
```